How to create multiple pivot tables with their own charts on the same sheet using a macro?
I am attempting to create several pivot tables on the same sheet each having their own chart. The goal is to do this every month as the data will be different monthly and the resulting pivot tables will have a dynamic range.
I can create each pivot table and apply their filters. However, when I create the charts for each table, I run into errors defining the source data.

Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'SetSourceData' of object '_Chart' failed

The dummy data I'm using is two columns with 1's and 0's each titled "Missing Form1" and "Missing Form2". The source data will be the same for each pivot table.
Sub Macro2()

    Dim pcLinkage As PivotCache
    Dim PivotTableName As PivotTable
    Dim PivotTableName2 As PivotTable
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim Form1Chart As ChartObject
    Dim Form2Chart As ChartObject
    
    ' Create pivot cache
    Set pcLinkage = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Link").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address)
    
    ' Add a new worksheet
    Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
    
    ' Create first pivot table
    Set PivotTableName = pcLinkage.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=wsNew.Name & "!R1C1", TableName:= _
        "PivotTableName")
    
    ' Add data field to first pivot table
    With PivotTableName
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Missing Form1"), _
            "Count of Missing Form1", xlCount
    End With
    
    ' Create chart for first pivot table
    Set Form1Chart = wsNew.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Top:=200, Width:=550, Height:=200)
    With Form1Chart.Chart
'This works exactly as intended. In my live workbook, the filter methods and formatting are applied correctly'
        .SetSourceData Source:=PivotTableName.TableRange1
        .ChartWizard Source:=PivotTableName.TableRange1, _
            Gallery:=xlColumn, Title:="Missing Form1 Turnbacks", HasLegend:=False
    End With
    
    ' Create second pivot table
    Set PivotTableName2 = pcLinkage.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=wsNew.Name & "!R1C4", TableName:= _
        "PivotTableName2")
    
    ' Add data field to second pivot table
    With PivotTableName2
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Missing Form2"), _
            "Count of Missing Form2", xlCount
    End With
    
    ' Create chart for second pivot table
    Set Form2Chart = wsNew.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=300, Top:=500, Width:=550, Height:=200)
    With Form2Chart.Chart
'This is where the error occurs'
        .SetSourceData Source:=PivotTableName2.TableRange1
'I tried to use this .ChartWizard by itself but it creates a chart using the data from PivotTableName'
        .ChartWizard Source:=PivotTableName2.TableRange1, _
            Gallery:=xlColumn, Title:="Missing Form2", HasLegend:=False
    End With

End Sub

I tried making this into a Shape and explicitly defining the range of the pivot table but run into the same error.
I tried using the .ChartWizard method, but it makes each chart connected and use PivotTableName data (same filters, same data series) instead of PivotTableName2, etc.
I tried to create a new pivot cache for the second pivot table but I ran into the same issues.
